# how to use laravel Route system in another php projects?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, illuminate

i am creating a php project for myself and it is not on laravel, i install [illuminate/database package](https://github.com/illuminate/database) on my project for using elequent and its work perfectly.
now i want to use laravel routing system in my project but can not find any Instructions for this
is there any way to use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can use all illuminate component like router in your project.you should see : https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch Torch is a project to provide instructions and examples for using Illuminate components as standalone components in non-Laravel applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do too if you like that. https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like another package that works much similar to Laravel routing, take a look at [Klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php).